# Word Counting program not producing desired output

Tags: c, word-count

I am referring K&R for learning C. I am not getting the desired output for the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
main()
{
    int c,nl,nw,nc, state;
    nl = nc = nw = 0;
    state = OUT;
    while ((c=getchar()!= EOF))
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            ++nl;
        }
        if (c ==' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", nc, nw,nl);
}
```

I gave the following input

```
the
door is
open
```

The output I obtained was

```
17 1 0
```

Kindly tell me what's wrong in the code.

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: '(c=getchar()!= EOF)' --> '(c=getchar())!= EOF'

Comment: Enable *compiler warnings*, `-Wall -Wextra` on gcc, `-Weverything` for clang or `/Wall` for VS (`cl.exe`) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Comment: But you didn't say what the program was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

`c=getchar()!= EOF` is wrong. This will first call function `getchar()`. Then it will compare the return value with `EOF`. After that, the result of the comparison, which will be 1 or 0, will be assigned to `c`.

To avoid this, use `(c=getchar()) != EOF` instad.

Instead of the second if statement, use `if(isspace(c))` (Thanks to Lundin for pointing it out)

You should also specify that main should return an int to avoid warnings.

Comment: Or use `isspace()` from ctype.h.

Comment: @Lundin True. Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: This will count consecutive spaces as words. The OP's state variable covers that case

Comment: And declaring `c` as `char` won't do. `getchar()` returns an `int`, to distinguish `EOF` from char 255 (or -1 if signed)

Comment: @king_nak I think I need some sleep. Total brain freeze. Thanks.